# Xcode Swift SKAction.follow start point

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to make a spaceship orbit around a planet. I am currently doing

```
let playerPos = player.position
let planetPos = planet.position

let radius = playerPos.x - planetPos.x

let rect = CGRect(x: planetPos.x - radius, y: planetPos.y - radius, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius)

let bezPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 0)
let path = bezPath.cgPath

let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path)
shape.strokeColor = .blue
shape.zPosition = 10
self.addChild(shape)

let move = SKAction.follow(path, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
```

and this does create the correct path, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k46r.jpg)

However, when I try to run the `move` action, the player teleports directly below the planet and then starts following the path. Is there a way to make it start following the path from where the player currently is? I am open to totally changing how I am going about making the ship move in a circle, as long as he starts where he is, and circles around a planet.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use [CGMutablePath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath) instead

```
let dx = playerPos.x - planetPos.x
let dy = playerPos.y - planetPos.y
let currentTheta = atan(dy / dx)
let endTheta = currentTheta + CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)

let newPath = CGMutablePath.init()
newPath.move(to: player.position)
newPath.addArc(center: planetPos, radius: radius, startAngle: currentTheta, endAngle: endTheta, clockwise: false)

let move = SKAction.follow(newPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(move))
```

The `newPath.move(to: player.position)` line starts the path at the ship's position and the `newPath.addArc` line draws a circle from the player's position and does a 360-degree rotation around the planet ending up back at the player's position.

Comment: Couldnt you have just done this: `let rect = CGRect(x: radius, y: radius, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius)` `let bezPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like the player to move from his current position to some position on the path, and then start following that path.

If so, you could consider running another action to first move the player from his current position to some starting point on the path, e.g. `CGPoint(x: planetPos.x - radius, y: planetPos.y - radius)`. Then once the player is on that point, run the `move` action you have defined. You can use `SKAction.sequence` to run actions one after the other.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not achieve the goal I was looking for. It might have worked in other instances, but in my case, the objects had physics bodies and would have collided if I tried something like that. (I want them to collide, but not in this instance)